# print all pairs that multiply equals input atleast one of them is primary

Tags: c++

For a user integer input I want to write a code to return : all the pairs of numbers that multiplied togther equals the input.
Criterias :

1. each pair only printed once
2. all numbers are integers
3. at least one number in the pair is primary
4. first print the smaller number in the pair
5. each pair in seperate row
6. don't use break or continue
7. don't use array

I wrote a code that uses functions which I need help in modifying the code without the functions and to apply to the creterias

**for input 20 the output should be
2,10
4, 5**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool checkIfPrime(int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if(num % i == 0)  
      {    
          return false;  
      }  
    }      
    return true;
}
bool dividable(int n1,int n2){
    if (n2 % n1 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }  
}
int main(){
    int armySize;
    bool isPrime;
    cout << "Please enter John Snow's Army Count:" << endl;
    cin >> armySize;
    for (int j = 2; j*j <= armySize; j++)
    {
        if (dividable(j,armySize))
        {
            if (checkIfPrime(j) == true || checkIfPrime(armySize/j) == true)
            {
                if (j < armySize)
                {
                    cout << j << ", " << armySize/j << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << armySize/j << ", " << j << endl;
                }
            
            }
        
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere. What's the problem with the shown code?

Comment: The "no arrays" seems a giant obstacle to me....

Comment: Can you use a ```std::map``` ?

Comment: `if (j < armySize)` this is always true.

Comment: code is wrong , cany anyone help fix it ?

Comment: Please explain how it is wrong. There is some unnecessary code there, but it fulfills the criteria and there is nothing obviously wrong with it.